# Usage of "might have ..."

Tags: phrase-meaning

The Godfather/chapt. IX:

> Sonny and Tom were off-center on this guy Sollozzo, they were still
>   underrating him, even though Sonny was smart enough to see the danger.
>   Michael tried to think what the turk *might have up his sleeves*.

The phrase confused me is `might have up his sleeves`, I can't connect *might have* and `up his sleeves` here. I thought if we making some kind of predicition about past events we should use `might have + pp`, but here is no any `pp` in the sentence.

Comment: There *have* is not a helper/auxiliary but is the main verb.  You might have a Ferrari in your garage, or you might not. I don't know. You might have an ace up your sleeve. Might = it is possible that...

Comment: "...*what* the turk might have up his sleeves".   What = pronoun what ~ what thing.  Have=possess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means *the turk* has some secret plan or scheme.

Up (someone's) sleeves is an idiom which means that someone has something in his/er mind as a part of some plan/game/secret or the like.

In the context, Michael wondered that what he *(the turk)* might have some plan/secret to work on.